# Kernel irq disable

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, yocto, interrupt-handling

I am using P2041 with kernel 3.12. I am using xr17v358 for serial interface. When I run serial interface it shows "try to boot with irqpoll" , " disabling irq" and so many trace messages. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: This means that no irq handler is registered or configured irq is not supported by buggy hardware/firmware. You may be getting kernel trace messages, if you can share them. Also, check the irq is owned by your driver or not in - `cat /proc/interrupts`

Comment: Does bug occurs on latest vanilla, I.e. v4.10.1?

Comment: I have not checked with latest version.

Comment: I have added irqpoll option in uboot environment variable. My problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to boot with "irqpoll" option in uboot kernel command line. This will help the kernel to find proper ISR. After enabling this option your system may get slow.